# Insignificant coefficients when estimating ARMA model with order proposed by AIC

Tags: statistical-significance, arima, model-selection, aic

I selected the p,q order for ARMA model based on AIC. The AIC suggests that the best order is ARMA(5,5). Although the coefficient is significant for AR 5 it is not significant for AR 1 and AR3 in the mean equation. Is this normal or should I change the order?

[image]

Comment: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tests2/

Comment: Thank you! I am comparing the returns of two series, both have different order for p,q as per AIC. ARMA (5,5) is suggested for 1 st series and ARMA(4,4) is suggested for 2nd series. 2nd series has the third least AIC with ARMA(5,5). Is it okay to use ARMA(5,5) for both series in this case?